# Querying Calendar ICS

Tags: android, calendar

I try to read out all existing calendars. I tried the example from here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html

but I get following compile error: The method getContentResolver() is undefined for the type xxx
Can somebody help me please?

```
public HashMap<String, String> readCalendar() {     
String[] EVENT_PROJECTION = new String[] {
        Calendars._ID,   
        Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT,                    
        Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME,                  
        Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME                                   
    };
    String selectionICS = "((" + Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME + " = ?) AND (" 
            + Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " = ?) AND ("
            + Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT + " = ?))";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {"VISIBLE=1"}; // or "selected=1" ??

    Cursor managedCursor = null;
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        managedCursor = cr.query(calendarUri, EVENT_PROJECTION, selectionICS, selectionArgs, null);selectionICS, selectionArgs, null);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getContentResolver()` is a method of `Context`, so my guess is that your class is not derived from `Activity` (which is derived from `Context`).

You have to use a context variable if you want to call it outside of an activity class (`context.getContentResolver()`). If your class is a BroadcastReceiver then the context variable is given as an argument in `onReceive()`. If not, you have to send it to your method when you call it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it is compilable, but managedCursor is null after read out. Can you see the mistake?

Comment: If your goal is to get all calendars then you don't need to filter the results, so don't use more than 2 parameters : `cr.query(calendarUri, EVENT_PROJECTION, null, null, null);`

Comment: it works. How can I get a HashMap from the courser? I updated my questen.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you, but please don't ask too many questions here, you should create a new one since it's not really related to the original question.

Comment: (And I don't know the answer, sorry)

Comment: Oh sorry, I changed it to the original question and wwill ask a new one. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Hello, one more question. I need just the selected calendars, how can I do that? Here the selection is null:cr.query(calendarUri, EVENT_PROJECTION, null, null, null); But I need asomething like that: cr.query(calendarUri, EVENT_PROJECTION, selection, null, null); but how should the selection look like? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Well I don't know much about calendars, sorry.

Comment: I figured it out: String selection = Calendars.VISIBLE + "=?"; String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {"1"};   cr.query(calendarUri, EVENT_PROJECTION, selection, selectionArgs, null); Thanks anyways!